# Selecting most common month from DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it somehow possible to select the most common and the least common month among all rows?
Let's say I have a column date with these values:

```
|       date        |
 -------------------
 2016-01-21 01:51:21
 2015-05-21 01:51:21
 2015-04-21 01:51:21
 2014-05-21 01:51:21
 2016-05-21 01:51:21 
 2015-04-21 01:51:21
```

So the idea is to select the most common and the least common month from this table. So for the first one it will be May (appearing 3 times), and the second one January (appearing only once). Is it possible to do that with a simple query?
Is it better to split the date to 3 separated columns (year, month and day) since I will need the same thing for the year from that date.

Comment: "Is it better to split the date to 3 separated columns" Almost certainly not - there are plenty of ways to decompose a date so it's not worth the risk of having out-of-sync data.  At most I _might_ add _computed_ columns if it would make the queries a bit cleaner.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL? Many of the vendors have their own date functions.

Comment: @TomH I'm using MySQL.

Comment: In general I would group by month (using whatever date functions are appropriate), order by count and get the first and last rows.

Comment: @DStanley I'm not so great at SQL so an example would be helpful.

Comment: Look in the mysql manual. Read the tutorial section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by and count lines like this:

```
SELECT month("date"), count(*)
  FROM "table"
 GROUP BY month("date");
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should give you the count of each month.

```
    SELECT DATEPART(mm, date) month
            ,COUNT(DATEPART(mm, date)) monthCount
    FROM [YourTable]

    GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, date)
```

Comment: It actually give me a fatal error saying that the function DATEPART doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah Sorry - Didn't notice you were in MySQL.  This is for Microsoft T-SQL.  Thanks for letting me know!